# How to iterate JSON HashMap

Tags: jquery, json

I have an json Object like this.

```
{'01/19/2012': Array[1],'02/19/2012': Array[7],'03/19/2012': Array[6]}
```

Now i want to iterate this map

I need result like

```
Date : 01/19/2012
      Array Data here

Date : 02/19/2012
      Array Data here
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a for loop in which you use condition: "var x in y" where y is the object.

```
for (var key in p) {
  if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    alert(key + " -> " + p[key]);
  }
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/684692/680578

Answer (score -1):

Use a "for ... in" loop.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for_in.asp

If you need to sort the data (as you might with dates), use "for ... in" to push the elements into an Array, use sort(), and then process the results.

More on sort(): http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp